# error: no matching function for call to ‘rectangle::rectangle(int, int)’

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class rectangle
{
public:

    T length;
    T breadth;
public:
    T area();
};

template <class T>
T rectangle<T>::area()
{
    return length * breadth;
}

int main()
{
    rectangle<int> r1(10, 5);
    cout << "area: " << r1.area() << endl;
}
```

Error as follows:

```
main.cpp:31:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘rectangle::rectangle(int, int)’
     rectangle<int> r1(10, 5);
```

I have a very hard time understanding what really caused the error here,and advance thanks!

Comment: You didn't define any constructors for `rectangle`.

Comment: but i initialised value when initialised object, isn't that enough?

Comment: `rectangle<int> r1{10, 5};` is the valid syntax.

Comment: `r1(10, 5)` is a constructor call, not an initializer. The initializer syntax would be `r1 = { 10, 5 }` or (starting in C++11) `r1{ 10, 5 }`.

Comment: Duudee, thankyouu!!!!!! And sorry for your time.